# How do you create a data table from json in C# (visual basic)

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, csv, datatable

I have inherited a project using Visual Studio (.NET Framework 4.7.2, I think). I'm receiving a response from an API endpoint with multiple entries which looks like so:

```json
[
    {
        "transaction_id": "00000352",
        "transaction_type": "New",
        "transaction_date": "2018-08-23T00:00:00",
        "sold_to_id": "00026",
        "customer_po_number": "34567",
        "po_date": "2018-08-23T00:00:00",
        "notes": null,
        "batch_code": "######",
        "location_id": "MN",
        "req_ship_date": "2018-08-28T00:00:00",
        "fiscal_period": 8,
        "fiscal_year": 2018,
        "currency_id": "USD",
        "original_invoice_number": null,
        "bill_to_id": "00026",
        "customer_level": null,
        "terms_code": "30-2",
        "distribution_code": "01",
        "invoice_number": null,
        "invoice_date": "2018-08-23T00:00:00",
        "sales_rep_id_1": null,
        "sales_rep_id_1_percent": 100,
        "sales_rep_id_1_rate": 0,
        "sales_rep_id_2_id": "SA",
        "sales_rep_id_2_percent": 100,
        "sales_rep_id_2_rate": 10,
        "ship_to_id": null,
        "ship_via": null,
        "ship_method": null,
        "ship_number": null,
        "ship_to_name": "",
        "ship_to_attention": null,
        "ship_to_address_1": null,
        "ship_to_address_2": null,
        "ship_to_city": null,
        "ship_to_region": null,
        "ship_to_country": "USA",
        "ship_to_postal_code": null,
        "actual_ship_date": null,
        "order_line_list": [
            {
                "entry_number": 1,
                "item_id": "5' Glass/Wood Table",
                "description": "Glass/ Wood Combo Coffee Table",
                "customer_part_no": null,
                "additional_description": null,
                "location_id": "MN",
                "quantity_ordered": 11,
                "units": "EA",
                "quantity_shipped": 0,
                "quantity_backordered": 0,
                "req_ship_date": null,
                "unit_price": 599.99,
                "extended_price": 6599.89,
                "reason_code": null,
                "account_code": null,
                "inventory_gl_account": "120000",
                "sales_gl_account": "400000",
                "cogs_gl_account": "500000",
                "sales_category": null,
                "tax_class": 0,
                "promo_id": null,
                "price_id": null,
                "discount_type": 0,
                "discount_percentage": 0,
                "discount_amount": 0,
                "sales_rep_id_1": null,
                "sales_rep1_percent": null,
                "sales_rep1_rate": null,
                "sales_rep_id_2": "SA",
                "sales_rep2_percent": 100,
                "sales_rep2_rate": 5,
                "unit_cost": 241.4467,
                "extended_cost": 2655.91,
                "status": "Open",
                "extended_list": [],
                "serial_list": []
            }
        ],
        "tax_group_id": "ATL",
        "taxable": false,
        "tax_class_adjustment": 0,
        "freight": 0,
        "tax_class_freight": 0,
        "tax_location_adjustment": null,
        "misc": 0,
        "tax_class_misc": 0,
        "sales_tax": 0,
        "taxable_sales": 0,
        "non_taxable_sales": 6599.89,
        "payment_list": []
    }
]
```

I would like to select individual key-value pairs from this response and create a data table. I'm extremely new (and somewhat allergic) to C# but I have tried doing this:

```
var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(response.Content);
JsonElement root = doc.RootElement;

//Console.WriteLine(doc.RootElement);
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Root Elem: {0}", doc.RootElement));

//creat data table
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("jsonObject col: {0}", jsonObject));
DataTable jsdt = jsonObject[doc.RootElement].ToObject<DataTable>();

int totalRows = jsdt.Rows.Count;


Console.WriteLine(String.Format("jsonObject col: {0}", jsonObject));

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("totalRows col: {0}", totalRows));
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("jsdt col: {0}", jsdt.Rows.Count));
```

I can't seem to get the DataTable to log to the console and have no idea if I'm actually creating the DataTable at all. I can loop through the JSON response to find individual key-value pairs but writing things to a DataTable is where I'm stuck. This is how I'm looping through the JSON:

```
var users = root.EnumerateArray();

while (users.MoveNext())
{
    var user = users.Current;
    //System.Console.WriteLine(user);

    var props = user.EnumerateObject();

    while (props.MoveNext())
    {
        var prop = props.Current;
        //Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Name}: {prop.Value}");
        if (prop.Name == "transaction_date") {
            //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("key: {0}", $"{prop.Name}: {prop.Value}"));
        }
    }
}
```

How would one go about creating a `DataTable` in this way?

**Update**:

My ultimate purpose is to create a CSV and ship it to another server.

I recognize that a CSV file is basically a 2d array of primitive values but that my JSON objects contain nested arrays of complex objects (e.g. `[*].order_line_list[*]`) which will need to be flattened somehow.  For this purpose flattening into multiple rows would be fine, e.g. parent name, parent info, nested item info 1; parent name, parent info, nested item info 2;

Comment: Your JSON contains a nested array of objects `[*].order_line_list[*]`.  How do you want to convert that into a `DataTable`?  A `DataTable` is basically an a 2d array of primitive values. While it's possible to store an array of complex objects as the values for one of the columns, it can cause problems with binding down the road.

Comment: Also, why are you mixing code from two different JSON serializers?  `JsonDocument` and `JsonElement` are from `System.Text.Json` while `JObject` is from Json.NET.  Since Json.NET has built-in support for data tables, you might want to stick with that exclusively.

Comment: No, rhyme nor reason for the mixing, simply just trying to get a data table with the return. As for getting values from the order_line_list items I was thinking I would have a nested loop with a conditional statement to return the key values I wanted. But I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the datatable after you deserialize it?

Comment: Create a CSV and ship it to another server.

Comment: As for the use of JsonDocument, it was taken from another example and it gave me the RootElement which I used to loop through things, But again I'm open to suggestions here for the sake of best practice/personal improvement.

Comment: OK, then putting aside the DataTable for a moment, what do you want to do for the nested array of objects when it has more than one item?  Do you want to create multiple CSV rows?  Or create multiple CSV columns with numbered names?  If you can show your final desired CSV output when say `[0].order_line_list[*]` has multiple elements, we can make some suggestions on how to get there.

Comment: Multiple rows would be fine, eg 
parent name, parent info, nested item info 1;
parent name, parent info, nested item info 2;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic problem here is that you have a JSON array containing JSON objects with possibly non-primitive object and array values, and you would like to eventually export that to CSV.  However, a CSV file is essentially a 2d array of **primitive** values, so you will need to flatten the non-primitives into primitives.  In order to do this, you may either

1. Extend the CSV horizontally by adding extra columns for nested values.
2. Extend the CSV vertically by adding extra rows for nested values.

You chose option 2, *Multiple rows would be fine, eg parent name, parent info, nested item info 1; parent name, parent info, nested item info 2;*

To do that, we're going to need two third-party tools, the [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) from [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) to parse your arbitrary JSON objects, and [`CsvWriter`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/CsvWriter.cs) from [`CsvHelper`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/) to write a CSV file.

First, introduce the following extension method to flatten a LINQ to JSON [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) into an enumerable of enumerable of key/value pairs of primitive JSON values:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JValue>>> FlattenChildrenIntoRows(this JObject obj)
    {
        bool anyReturned = false;
        var simpleChildren = obj.Properties().Where(p => p.Value is JValue).Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, JValue>(p.Name, (JValue)p.Value)).ToList();
        var complexChildren = obj.Properties().Where(p => !(p.Value is JValue)).Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, JToken>(p.Name, p.Value));
        foreach (var property in complexChildren)
        {
            foreach (var flattenedItems in FlattenChildrenIntoRows(property))
            {
                yield return simpleChildren.Concat(flattenedItems);
                anyReturned = true;
            }
        }

        if (!anyReturned)
            yield return simpleChildren;
    }

    static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JValue>>> FlattenChildrenIntoRows(KeyValuePair<string, JToken> property) 
    {
        if (property.Value is JValue value)
        {
            yield return new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, JValue>(property.Key, value) };
        }
        else if (property.Value is JArray array)
        {
            foreach (var item in array)
                foreach (var flattenedItem in FlattenChildrenIntoRows(new KeyValuePair<string, JToken>(property.Key, item)))
                    yield return flattenedItem;
        }
        else if (property.Value is JObject obj)
        {
            foreach (var flattenedItems in FlattenChildrenIntoRows(obj))
                yield return flattenedItems.Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, JValue>(property.Key + "." + p.Key, p.Value));
        }
        else // JRaw, JContainer
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Next, introduce the following method to write a list of `Dictionary<string, string>` objects to a CSV file, making the dictionary keys be the CSV column names:

```
public static partial class CsvExtensions
{
    public static void WriteCsv(TextWriter writer, IReadOnlyList<IDictionary<string, string>> objects, CsvConfiguration config)
    {
        var headers = objects.SelectMany(o => o.Keys).Distinct();
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, config))
        {
            foreach (var header in headers)
                csv.WriteField(header);
            csv.NextRecord();
            foreach (var obj in objects)
            {
                foreach (var header in headers)
                    if (obj.TryGetValue(header, out var value))
                        csv.WriteField(value);
                    else
                        csv.WriteField(null);
                csv.NextRecord();
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

And now we can combine these two methods to read a JSON array, flatten it, and write to CSV as follows:

```
public static partial class CsvExtensions
{
    /// Convert a JSON file to a CSV file
    public static void ConvertJsonToCsv(string inputPath, string outputPath)
    {
        using var reader = new StreamReader(inputPath);
        using var writer = new StreamWriter(outputPath);
        ConvertJsonToCsv(reader, writer);
    }
    
    /// Read JSON from the incoming TextReader, convert to CSV and write to the incoming TextWriter
    public static void ConvertJsonToCsv(TextReader reader, TextWriter writer)
    {
        // Disable reformatting of dates
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        };
        
        using var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader) { CloseInput = false };
        
        // Deserialize to an array of objects
        
        var array = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings).Deserialize<List<JObject>>(jsonReader);
        
        // Flatten and convert to a List<Dictionary<string, string>>
        
        var list = array
            // Flatten each child into an enumerable of enumerable of primitive key/value pairs
            .Select(o => o.FlattenChildrenIntoRows())
            // Project and flatten to an overall enumerable of enumerable of pairs
            .SelectMany(pairs => pairs)
            // Convert to an overall enumerable of dictionaries
            .Select(pairs => pairs.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value.Value == null ? null : (string)Convert.ChangeType(p.Value.Value, typeof(string), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
            // Materialize as a list of dictionaries
            .ToList();
        
        // Write to CSV
        var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        CsvExtensions.WriteCsv(writer, list, config);
    }
}
```

Which you might call like:

```
using var reader = new StringReader(response.Content);
using var writer = new StringWriter();

CsvExtensions.ConvertJsonToCsv(reader, writer);

var csvText = writer.ToString();

Console.WriteLine(csvText);
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MQhoPY).

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication37
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            string pattern = "\"(?'key'[^\"]+)\":\\s+(?'value'[^,]+)";
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = matches.Cast<Match>()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Groups["key"].Value, y => y.Groups["value"].Value.Trim())
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());


        }
    }
}
```